# Sitecore optimization for local development

Tags: best-practices, performance-optimization

We have big Sitecore solution that is taking long time to load. We need to optimize the code obviously.

But from pure Sitecore configuration point of view, what we can adjust for local development ?

E.g.

- Enabling debug
- Disable HTML cache
- ...

We are usign Sitecore 8.2 currently.

Comment: You can start with this: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/02/sitecore-8-experience-editor-performance-optimization/

Answer (score 1):

Please try to disable some of the below config in local dev to improve the performance.

1-disable content testing

```
<sitecore>
    <settings>
        <setting name="ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
</sitecore>
```

2-disables memory hooks and memory measurements

```
<pipelines>
  <httpRequestEnd>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StopMeasurements, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <ShowThresholdWarnings>false</ShowThresholdWarnings>
      <TimingThreshold desc="Milliseconds">1000000</TimingThreshold>
      <ItemThreshold desc="Item count">1000000</ItemThreshold>
      <MemoryThreshold desc="KB">10000000</MemoryThreshold>
    </processor>
  </httpRequestEnd>
  <healthMonitor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HealthMonitor.HealthMonitor, Sitecore.Kernel" method="LogCounterStatus">
      <patch:delete />
    </processor>
  </healthMonitor>
</pipelines>

<hooks>
  <hook type="Sitecore.Diagnostics.MemoryMonitorHook, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <patch:delete />
  </hook>
</hooks>
```

3- disables some startup pipelines  that are not needed

```
    <pipelines>
        <initialize>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel"><patch:delete /></processor>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory, Sitecore.Kernel"><patch:delete /></processor>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo, Sitecore.Analytics"><patch:delete /></processor>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.DumpConfigurationFiles, Sitecore.Kernel"><patch:delete /></processor>
        </initialize>
    </pipelines>
```

4-if Content testing is disabled

```
<contentSearch>
    <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
            <!-- Solr Index-->
            <index id="sitecore_suggested_test_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
                    <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
                        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                            <field fieldName="impact" returnType="double">
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                            <field fieldName="potential" returnType="double">
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                            <field fieldName="recommendation" returnType="double">
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                        </fieldNames>
                    </fieldMap>
                    <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">
                        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                            <field fieldName="impact" returnType="double" type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestImpactMetric, Sitecore.ContentTesting" >
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                            <field fieldName="potential" returnType="double" type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestPotentialMetric, Sitecore.ContentTesting" >
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                            <field fieldName="recommendation" returnType="double" type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestRecommendationMetric, Sitecore.ContentTesting" >
                                <patch:delete />
                            </field>
                        </fields>
                    </documentOptions>
                </configuration>
            </index>
        </indexes>
    </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

5- index updates more rarely

```
<scheduling>
<!-- Update this agent so it doesn"t run every 10 seconds. Appears to be related to email contact management. -->
<agent type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent, Sitecore.ListManagement">
    <patch:attribute name="interval">00:30:00</patch:attribute>
</agent>

<agent type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <patch:attribute name="interval">08:00:00</patch:attribute>
</agent>

<!-- Never automatically build core or master index -->
<agent name="Core_Database_Agent">
    <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:00</patch:attribute>
</agent>
<agent name="Master_Database_Agent">
    <patch:attribute name="interval">00:30:00</patch:attribute>
</agent>
```